# How to fix java.lang.AbstractMethodError in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-paging-3, epoxy

I switched from a recyclerview to using an epoxy list controler to display the results of a web response in my application. My response is handled in the right way and is transfered in my model class. Unfortunately after I received the response I got an error. The error looks like this:

```
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.lang.Object androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer.presentNewList(androidx.paging.NullPaddedList, androidx.paging.NullPaddedList, int, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0, kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)"
    at androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer$collectFrom$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(PagingDataDiffer.kt:151)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I tried to find a solution but can´t find someone with the same error as me. I updated everything in my gradle files but I keep getting the same error.
I´m not familiar with such a problem and can´t find a helpful solution on my own!

I would be thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in my case was to delete:

`//implementation "androidx.paging:paging-compose:1.0.0-alpha14"`

Now it is working!